# Finding all possible pairs of subsets using recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am given

```
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and the table of points:

```
point tab[MAX];
```

Program should return the minimal distance between the centers of gravity of any possible pair of subsets from `tab`. Subset can be any size (of course >=1 and <  MAX).
I am obliged to write this program using recursion.

So my function will be `int` type because I have to return `int`.
I globally set variable `min` (because while doing recurssion I have to compare some values with this min)

```
int min = 0;
```

My function should for sure, take number of elements I add, sum of Y coordinates and sum of X coordinates.

```
int return_min_distance(int sY, int sX, int number, bool iftaken[])
```

I will be glad for any help further.
I thought about another table of bools which I pass as a parameter to determine if I took value or not from table. Still my problem is how to implement this, I do not know how to even start.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried for `return_min_distance()`?

Comment: @Randall Cook I think it can be classified as homework problem. It is one of problems which appeared on test years ago, and I am preparing to pass this test and recursion is my weakest point.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted your question, but it has been my experience that homework problems are frowned upon here. Just and FYI.

Comment: @RandallCook Only homework questions that show little to no attempt at solving the problem oneself.

Comment: @zero298 Not really, still thinking how to implement this. I have problems with concept, how this function should look like.

Comment: @MarcinMajewski can you give an example of what you supposed to do here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a function that can iterate through all subsets of the table, starting with either nothing or an existing iterator. The code then gets easy:

```
int min_distance = MAXINT;
SubsetIterator si1(0, tab);
while (si1.hasNext())
{
    SubsetIterator si2(&si1, tab);

    while (si2.hasNext())
    {
        int d = subsetDistance(tab, si1.subset(), si2.subset());

        if (d < min_distance)
        {
            min_distance = d;
        }
    }
}
```

The SubsetIterators can be simple base-2 numbers capable of counting up to MAX, where a 1 bit indicates membership in the subset. Yes, it's a O(N^2) algorithm, but I think it has to be.

The trick is incorporating recursion. Sorry, I just don't see how it helps here. If I can think of a way to use it, I'll edit my answer.

**Update**: I thought about this some more, and while I still can't see a use for recursion, I found a way to make the subset processing easier. Rather than run through the entire table for every distance computation, the SubsetIterators could store precomputed sums of the x and y values for easy distance computation. Then, on every iteration, you subtract the values that are leaving the subset and add the values that are joining. A simple bit-and operation can reveal these. To be even more efficient, you could use [gray coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) instead of two's complement to store the membership bitmap. This would guarantee that at each iteration exactly one value enters and/or leaves the subset. Minimal work.